# Why is "Event: When an Item is changed" triggered when on all items in the list?

Tags: workflow, item

I have an action: 
Wait for Event: When an item is changed (Output to Variable: related item1 ).

From what I can tell, this event is triggered whenever ANY item in this list is changed. So, all the workflows attached to different items in the list are restarting.

It can also be possible that all items in the list are updated when a single item is modified by the user.

In any case, this is not workable for me to send an email when an item is changed.

Answer (score 2):

**Wait for Event in List Item:** Used to wait for a new item to be created or an item to be changed. So if you use this action, it will be trigger whenever any item is changed in list.

If you want to send mail when **current item** is changed, refer following action in workflow:
**Wait for Field Change in Current Item:** Used to wait for a field to be changed in the current item.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected that it is exactly what was happening. When I was developing the workflow I had only 1 item to work with...

Answer (score 0):

What's the logic for your workflow? If it's modifying other items in the list, that would laucn the workflows on other items. Have you tried to stopp all workflows on all items, and start from scratch by modifying the first item, and check to see what's going on?